# c++ c99 template specialization with an Enum parameter without using integral_constant

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, enums, template-specialization

Basically, I am trying to use a enum which could do bit operations and there is a template function could map the enum element to array index. In the operator overload function I need 
a  compile-time constant expression.

I need something like integral_constant, but that is in c11 not in c99 anyone know how to implement integral_constant in c99?

OR

Any other ways to create the enum could performance bit operation and index an array?

Thanks~

```
enum E
{
  E_a=1,
  E_b=2,
  E_c=4,
  E_d=8,
  E_MAX=16,
};

// Template struct to compute the index 
template<int N>
struct I
{
  static const int idx = 1 + I<N/2>::idx;
};
template<>struct I<1>{ static const int idx= 0; };

// 
class Data
{
  static void Init()
  {
    data[E_a].value = 10;
    data[E_b].value = 20;
    data[E_c].value = 40;
    data[E_d].value = 80;
  }

  Data* operator[](const E& e)
  {
    return &(Data::data[I<e>::idx]); // <-Here is the problem, template parameter should be a constant expression but e is a parameter, even it is constant it is not a expression
  }
  // member variables
  void* value; 
  static Data data[I<E_MAX>::idx];
};
```

Comment: `enum`s in C++ are just ints, does the compiler have a problem with a specialisation? Post invocation? Errors?

Comment: It seems you've mixed up the languages. Templates, operator overloading, `std::integral_constant` etc. are C++ features (not C features). The last two versions of the C Standard are referred to as C99 and C11, but the last two versions of the C++ Standard are (C++98 or C++03) and C++11.

Comment: Integral constant can only be partially implemented in C++03, e.g. `template<class T, T t> integral_constant { typedef T value_type; typedef integral_constant type; static const T value = t; };` The member functions cannot be `constexpr` obviously, but they're not necessary (and you can provide them w/o `constexpr`). See, e.g. [cppreference.com : integral_constant](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant) (Note that w/o defining the static data member outside, you may not ODR-use it.)

Comment: @dyp Thanks for your answer. When I use `template<class T, T t>
struct integral_constant
{
 typedef T value_type;
 typedef integral_constant type;
 static const T value = t;
};`as integral_constant<E,e> The compiler yields "error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'const E'
error C2440: 'specialization' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'const E';error C2440:'specialization' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'E'error C2971:'int_const' : template parameter 't' : 'i' : a local variable cannot be used as a non-type argument;error C2973: 'int_const' : invalid template argument 'int'

Comment: The conversion errors can be fixed by using a `static_cast`. Note that an expression of a(n unscoped) enumeration type can be implicitly converted to an integral type, but not vice versa. The other problem is probably that you're trying to use a parameter (or local variable) as a non-type template argument. A template argument always needs to be a constant expression, and parameters are never (assumed to be) constant expressions. (Other local variables might be constant expressions if the variables are `const` and initialized from a constant expression.)

Comment: Yeah, constant expression is the original question. I mean I can not find a way to convert the parameter to constant expression. There is no constexpr in c99. That is why I was seeking thing like the implementation of integral_constant